# Naming output files in R

Tags: r, filenames, write.table

I'm working in `R` and I would like to export a txt file putting in its name the value of a particular variable; I read about the command `paste` and it works perfectly here:

```
write.table(mydata,file=paste(cn,"data.txt"))
```

where `cn` is the value to put at the beginning of the file `data.txt`. I would like to automatically put this file in an output folder where I keep all the other results. I try to do something like this:

```
write.table(mydata,file=paste(cn,"./output/data.txt"))
```

But it doesn't work. Any suggestion?

Comment: try paste0 instead of paste. paste adds spacing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`paste()` just creates a string by concatenating the individual values and uses a space as default separator:

```
write.table(mydata, file = paste("./output/", cn ,"data.txt", sep = ""))
```

or with `paste0(...)`, which is equivalent to `paste(..., sep = "")`:

```
write.table(mydata, file = paste0("./output/", cn ,"data.txt"))
```